# What is the javascript equivalent of the following?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can this be achieved using vanilla javascript? Following uses jQuery syntax.

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover"); 
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    );
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; "); 
});
```

Comment: jQuery is also JavaScript.

Comment: Come on, at least try to ask in such a way that people will want to help you...

Comment: Please edit your post and properly line-break and indent your code, using the formatting tools available in the future. That code was unreadable. Look at the edit revision Cerbrus made to figure out what they did. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: "He did", I'm just one person :P [/nitpicking]

Comment: @Cerbrus Not taking into account the fact that you used a name similar to the one of a three-headed dog ;) I - and many others - use 'they' when we don't know the gender of a person. =)

Comment: Apologies, total noob here. Using this site for the first time.

Comment: @J.Steen: that's a fair point.

Comment: @Amberlamps: jQuery is a library written in JavaScript for web browsers, but it won't run everywhere that JavaScript does.  Many say it's too heavyweight for some devices.

Comment: @user1644142: It might have been better to ask what the CSS equivalent is of all that, since I don't think any of that functionality is best suited to JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: I do know what jQuery is. As you already mentionend, jQuery is a framework written in JavaScript. Therefore the provided code snippet is already JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is similar:

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(){
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("ul.dropdown li");
        for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++){
            var e = elements[i];
            e.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
                e.setAttribute('class', e.getAttribute('class') + ' hover');
                document.querySelector("ul.dropdown li").style.visibility = 'visible';
                e.style.visibility = 'visible';
            })
            e.addEventListener('mouseout',  function(e){
                e.setAttribute('class', e.getAttribute('class').replace(' hover',''));
                document.querySelector("ul.dropdown li").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            })
        }
        document.querySelector("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").querySelector("a:first").innerHTML += " &raquo; "; 
    }
)
```

(But not the same)

Comment: Hey, that makes my life a lot easier. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually i just needed to understand the concept which was difficult wit the jQuery syntax. So that does help very much.

Comment: Oooh, so basically, it was a "What does this do?" question?